# Django: Providing initial group with migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

Since the using of an `initial_data` fixture is deprecated, I'm trying to add initial data with a migration.

I created my models, and one of the models contains a permission code-named `can_use_feature`.

When I run a `makemigrations`, a `0001_initial.py` migration is created. The `migrate` command creates the database, well populated and the permission from above is in the `auth_permission` table.

Now I want to have a group with that permission by default in the database, so I create this migration as `0002_default_group.py`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations


def create_default_group(apps, schema_editor):

    GroupModel = apps.get_model('auth', 'group')

    group = GroupModel(name='My Group')
    group.save()

    PermissionModel = apps.get_model('auth', 'permission')
    permission = PermissionModel.objects.get(codename='can_use_feature')
    group.permissions.add(permission)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_default_group),
    ]
```

Now something mysterious happens: When I delete the database again and execute the `migrate` command, an `DoesNotExist` error is raised, right at the `permission = PermissionModel.objects.get(codename='can_use_feature')` line.

When I remove the `0002_default_group.py`, delete the database, execute `migrate`, copy the `0002_default_group.py` back and run `migrate` again, everything works fine and the group is created in the way I want it.

What must be changed in order to get the migration to work in only one step?

Answer (score 4):

Permissions are created when the `post_migrate` signal fires. This signal is only fired if all migrations in the current run are completed. You cannot depend on the permissions existing within your migration.

The signal receiver that creates the permissions checks for existing permissions, so you can simply create the permission yourself if it doesn't exist yet.

It would also be good to add a dependency on `('auth', '__latest__')` to ensure that the migrations for the Permission model have run and at least the table exists.

Comment: So, for work database we do migrations in few steps:first, we migrate  `auth`, `site` and other apps, that use `post-migrate`, then migrate other apps. But what with testing database? it is not possible to tweak migrate process

Comment: I guess it wasn't entirely clear, but my point was that you shoulf create them yourself in `create_default_group()` if they don't exist at that point. Then you can run all migrations in one go.